# I am trying to replace the occurrences of \r to \r\n. It is also replacing the character before and after \r. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

```
String abc = "ABC\n\rDEF\rGHI\nJKL\n\rMNO\r\tPQR\t";
String cde = abc.replaceAll("[^\n]\r[^\t]", "\n\r");
System.out.println(cde);
```

The \r should be not be surrounded by \n or \t. For instance, I do not want to replace \n\r to \n\n\r.

Expected: "ABC\n\rDEF\n\rGHI\nJKL\n\rMNO\r\tPQR\t" 
Actual: "ABC\n\rDE\n\rHI\nJKL\n\rMNO\r\tPQR\t"

Comment: I don't think you have accurately described to us, with this title, "\r to \r\n", the expected behavior. The arguments to `replaceAll` don't match that either.

Comment: it sure is replacing the additional characters, in `[^\n]\r[^\t]`, the `[^\n]` part will find any character that is not `\n`, that is, it will match ONE character but `\n`; similar for `[^\t]` (maybe you can use the zero-width lookahaed or lookbehind [constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#pos_lookahead))

Comment: @clwhisk Sorry. Just updated the description. Hope its clear now.

Comment: Can't be sure because both have been presented.

Comment: "F\rH" matches [^\n]\r[^\t] and is getting replaced.  Look up regex parenthesized parameters (or capturing groups) which can be used in the replacement string to keep the matching segments you want to retain. E.g. "([^\n])\r([^\t])", "$1\n\r$2)"

Comment: I proceeded without using regex. Thanks y'all.
String abc = "ABC\n\rDEF\rGHI\nJKL\n\rMNO\r\tPQR\t";
String out1 = abc.replace("\n\r","!!!");
String out2 = out1.replace("\r\t","$$$");
String out3 = out2.replace("\r","\n\r");
String out4 = out3.replace("!!!","\n\r");
String out5 = out4.replace("$$$","\r\t");

Comment: @user16320675 Yes.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay I tried using capture groups, couldn't make it work.

Comment: @user16320675 the question title says `\r\n`. That's basically why I threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Linux line ending `\n` and the Windows line ending `\r\n`.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\R", "\r\n");
```

Uses the regex pattern for any line ending `\R` to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Re the comment left above (Sorry for the slow response)

Here is a regex101 sample of the groupings.

Note the need to use the escape character '\' which may be required depending on your language.  I used the expression

```
([^\\n])\\r([^\\t])
```

and the substitution string

```
$1\\n\\r$2
```

The result as shown is

```
ABC\n\rDEF\n\rGHI\nJKL\n\rMNO\r\tPQR\t
```

[image: regex101 example]